# Access 2010 - Having multiple products to one Quote ID

Tags: forms, ms-access, report, product

I have created an adaptation of the 'Goods' database that includes a quote feature. The user selects the customer (customer table), Product (product table), qty, discount ect.
The chosen entities then get saved to the quotes table and there is a 'print' function on form.

Whilst the information can be saved and the quote prints via a quote report, I'm having major difficulty in finding a way to add multiple products to a single quote.

**The main objective is to be able to select various products and add their total price (product after addition of qty, discount) to a SUB TOTAL**

Quote total is therefore the formula Tax+Shipping+SubTotal

any takers? :)

***Hi guys,***

Thanks for the response I really appreciate it. As for tax and shipping, they are just added in the form and are not pushed from anywhere else in the database. Its simply a type in form and display on report sort of thing. As you said in the answer, HansUp, the salesperson will compute it seperately and just input it.

As for tax, products will be shiped globally so the tax/vat shall be computed seperately also. 
Also, each table DOES have its own unique ID.

More to the point of having QuoteProducts. I can't seem to get my head around it! Are you saying that whatever products are chosen in QuoteProducts will create a QuoteProd_ID and then that ID's total price will therefore be added to the Quote?

I tried making a subform before but through the 'multiple records' form but obviously every selection made its own ID. Is there any way you could elaborate on the Quote products part and how it allows multiple records to store to one ID? Without understanding it i'm pretty much useless.
In addition, how the multiple records are then added up to make the subtotal also baffles me. Is that done in the Quote form?

**Edit 2**

HALLELUJAH.

It works! I created a sum in a textbox on the footer of the subform and then pushed that into subtotal :)

I do have one slight issue:

I made a lookup&relationship for the ListPrice. I don't think its the correct way to do it as it comes up with the price of every light (i.e 10 products priced £10, £10 shows up ten times in dropdown).

Can you guys help?

**List Price Problem**

here's what i've tried:

1) Create >Client>Query Design

2) Show Products, QuoteDetails. For some reason, it automtically comes up with ListPrice, ProductID (as it should) and Product Name linked to ID in Products

3) Delete links with ListPrice and ProductName.

4) Show all in quoteDetails (*)

5) Create Multiple Items form

Doesnt work! What am I doing wrong?

I'm extremely grateful for both your help. If I can do anything, just shout.

Ryan

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me,
tables are as follows:
Customers, products, employees, quote. 
the first 3 have relationships with the quote table.
As for the structure I am unsure!

Comment: that's the thing. I don't want the combo box, I just want the ListPrice to appear. I have the ProductID in the quoteDetails...do i just 'add existing field'?

Comment: Argh having problems with this.
I'll put a step by step in an edit. Could you please see where i'm going wrong? thanks

Comment: SELECT 
FROM Products INNER JOIN QuoteDetails ON (Products.ID = QuoteDetails.ListPrice) AND (Products.ID = QuoteDetails.ProductName) AND (Products.ID = QuoteDetails.ProductID);
This is what initially shows, i'm positive this is wrong though!

Comment: I know how to use the query designer, however the problem i was addressing is that when i select the products and quoteDetails tables it would automatically show relations between ID (in products) with ProductID (which is fine), ListPrice and ProductName in quoteDetails..

Comment: furthermore, the user will not be selecting the productID in the form, they will be selecting the product name, which in turn should show the products listPrice. By using the term 'lookup&relationship' i was referring to the using the 'lookup&relationship' field within the table design which resulted in a combo box. I though that would ultimately mean that the listPrice would therefore have a relationship with the appropriate price. i was obviously wrong!

Comment: I deleted the join conditions, though i thought that there was maybe something more to it all (possibly some sort of underlying condition)  seeing that these joins appeared automatically is all :) Apologies if I seemed defensive, probably due to how I type/me not stating exactly what i want as the outcome. I'm not new to access, though 2010 is something else it would seem. 
Thank you for your help anyway, I guess i'll have to tackle this demon myself. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

For the first 3 tables mentioned in your comment, each should have a primary key: Customers, customer_id; products, product_id; and employees, employee_id.

The quotes table will have its own primary key, quote_id, and will store customer_id and employee_id as foreign keys.  (I'm assuming you want employee_id to record which customer representative/salesperson created the quote.)  You may also decide to include additional attributes for each quote; date and time quote prepared, for example.

The products offered for quotes will be stored in a junction table, QuoteProducts.  It will have foreign keys for quote_id and product_id, with one row for each product offered in the quote.  This is also where you can store the attributes quantity and discount.  An additional field, unit_price, can allow you to store the product price which was effective at the time the quote was prepared ... which would be useful in case product prices change over time.  I don't know whether tax should be included in this table (see below).

I also don't know how to address shipping.  If all the products associated with a quote are intended to be delivered in one shipment, shipping cost could be an attribute of the quotes table.  I don't know how you intend to derive that value.  Seems like it might be determined by shipping method, distance, and weight.  If you have the salesperson compute that value separately, and then input the value, consider how to handle the case where the product selection changes after the shipping fee has been entered.

That design is somewhat simplistic, but might be sufficient for the situation you described.  However, it could get more complex.  For example, if you decide to maintain a history of product price changes, you would be better off to build in provisions for that now.  Also, I have no idea how tax applies in your situation --- whether it's a single rate applied to all products, varies by customer location, varies by type of customer, and/or varies by product.  Your business rules for taxes will need to be accommodated in the schema design.

However, if that design works for you (test it by entering dummy data into the tables without using a form), you could create a form based on quotes with a subform based on QuoteProducts.  With quote_id as the link master/child property, the subform will allow you to view all products associated with the main form's current quote_id.  You can use the subform to add, remove, and/or edit products associated with that quote.

Not much I can say about the report.  There is a lot of uncertainty in the preceding description.  However, if your data base design allows you to build a workable form/subform, it should also support a query which gathers the same data.  Use that query as the record source for the report.  And use the report's sorting and grouping features to create the quote grand total.

**Edit**: With the main form/ subform approach, each new row in the subform should "inherit" the quote_id value of the current record in the main form.  You ensure that happens by setting the link master/child properties to quote_id.  Crystal Long explains that in more detail in chapter 5 of *Access Basics by Crystal*: [PDF file](http://www.accessmvp.com/strive4peace/Access_Basics_Crystal_080113_Chapter_05.pdf).  Scroll down to the heading *Creating a Main Form and Subform* on page 24.

**Edit2**: Your strategy may include storing Products.ListPrice in QuoteDetails.ListPrice.  That would be useful to record the current ListPrice offered for a quote.  If so, you can fetch ListPrice from Products and store it in QuoteDetails when you select the ProductID for a row in the subform.  You can do that with VBA code in the after update event of the control which is bound to the ProductID field.  So if that control is a combo box named cboProductID and the subform control bound to the QuoteDetails ListPrice field is a text box named txtListPrice, use code like this for cboProductID after update:

```
Me.txtListPrice = DLookup("ListPrice", "Products", "ProductID = " _
    & Me.cboProductID)
```

That suggestion assumes the Products and QuoteDetails tables both include a ProductID field and its data type is numeric.  And cboProductID has ProductID as its bound field and uses a query as its RowSource similar to this:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName
FROM Products
ORDER BY ProductName;
```

Comment: please see the bottom of the question as I gave added abit more, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to HansUp's stellar answer, you might be interested in [DatabaseAnswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/). They have a number of data models for free that might provide additional insight to your situation and possibly serve as inspiration for future projects you may encounter.

**Edit 1**

Forget about the form and report for a moment - they are important but not as important as the data and how you store the data.

In your current design, you have a quotes table presumably with an autonumber key field. For the purposes of this answer, this field is named Quote_ID.

The quotes table, as HansUp suggested, should store information such as the Customer_ID, Employee_ID, OrderDate and perhaps even a reference to a BillingAddress and ShippingAddress.

The quotes table SHOULD NOT store anything about the products that the customer has ordered as part of this quote.

Instead, this information should be stored in a table called QuoteProducts or QuoteDetails.
It's structure would look something like the following:

```
QuoteDetails_ID --> Primary Key of the table (autonumber field)
Quote_ID --> Foreign key back to the Quotes table
Product_ID --> Foreign key back to Products table
Quantity
UnitPrice
```

You may also want to consider a field for tax and a separate field for shipping per line item on the quote. You will inevitably run into situations where certain items are taxable in some locations and not others, etc.

This design allows a particular quote to have any number of products assigned to the quote.

Returning to your form \ reports, you would need to change your existing forms and reports to accomodate this new table design. Typically one would use a main form for the quote itself, and then a subform for the quote details (item, price, quantity, etc).
To get the quote total, you would sum the items in QUoteDetails for a particular Quote_ID.

You may also want to check out the Northwind sample database from Microsoft. From what I recall Northwind had a sample Orders system that might help make these ideas more concrete for you by seeing a working example.

Comment: please see the bottom of the question as I gave added abit more, thank you!

Comment: Nice job, Tim.  Too bad I can't give you another upvote today.  :-)